# Android: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1389): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-99,java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, multithreading

In my app i have "MyService" class that it does backup from some data in phone and this is in thread in run(). also in another class i have this:

```
public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParentActivityData> CREATOR = new Creator<ParentActivityData>() {
    @Override
    public ParentActivityData createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
        return null;
    }
```

that i don't use it any where, when i press backup button i get this error:

```
ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1389): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-99
        java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.---.---.MyService$1.run(MyService.java:51)
```

how can i fix it???

**EDIT :**

```
package com.athena.paadbox.entity;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

public class ParentActivityData implements Parcelable {
    public List<SelectableEntity> listDataHeader;
    public HashMap<String, List<SelectableEntity>> listDataChild;

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParentActivityData> CREATOR = new Creator<ParentActivityData>() {
        @Override
        public ParentActivityData createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            ParentActivityData pad = new ParentActivityData();
            return pad;
        }

        @Override
        public ParentActivityData[] newArray(int i) {
            return new ParentActivityData[0];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    }
}
```

**EDIT :**

```
public class SelectableEntity implements Parcelable {
    public SelectableEntity parent = null;
    public String title = null;
    public boolean state = false;

    public SelectableEntity(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public SelectableEntity(SelectableEntity parent, String title) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    }
}
```

Comment: you need to return instance of ParentActivityData in createFromParcel(). (use Parcel parameter to read data that you have previously written) you may think that you are not using CREATOR anywhere, but android internally uses this field and calls createFromParcel() method...

Comment: @GopalRao: if i new PranetActivityData and return this, is ok?

Comment: first, is your ParentActivity class implements Parcelable? if so are you writing data into Parcel by overriding writeToParcel()?

Comment: @GopalRao : How can i do this?

Comment: ok. post your ParentActivityData class

Comment: @GopalRao: yes my class implements Parcelable, and i have this method but it's empty:@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    }

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43303/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-elham-gdz)

Comment: @GopalRao :if you can help me here i will so happy,thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this...

```
public class ParentActivityData implements Parcelable {
    public List<SelectableEntity> listDataHeader;
    public HashMap<String, List<SelectableEntity>> listDataChild;

    public ParentActivityData() {

    }

    private ParentActivityData(Parcel parcel) {
        listDataHeader = (List<SelectableEntity>) parcel.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());
        listDataChild = (HashMap<String, List<SelectableEntity>>) parcel.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<ParentActivityData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<ParentActivityData>() {
        @Override
        public ParentActivityData createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new ParentActivityData(parcel);
        }

        @Override
        public ParentActivityData[] newArray(int size) {
            return new ParentActivityData[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0xFEED;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeValue(listDataHeader);
        parcel.writeValue(listDataChild);
    }
}


public class SelectableEntity implements Parcelable {
    public SelectableEntity parent = null;
    public String title = null;
    public boolean state = false;
    // Don't use these constructors.
    /*public SelectableEntity(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public SelectableEntity(SelectableEntity parent, String title) {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.title = title;
    }*/

    public SelectableEntity() {

    }

    // use setters

    public void setParent(SelectableEntity parent) {
        this.parent = parent;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public void setState(boolean state) {
        this.state = state;
    }

    private SelectableEntity(Parcel parcel) {
        parent = parcel.readParcelable(getClass().getClassLoader());
        title = parcel.readString();
        state = (Boolean) parcel.readValue(getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0xFEED;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeParcelable(parent, flags);
        parcel.writeString(title);
        parcel.writeValue((Boolean)state);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<SelectableEntity> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MainActivity.SelectableEntity>() {

        @Override
        public SelectableEntity createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new SelectableEntity(source);
        }

        @Override
        public SelectableEntity[] newArray(int size) {
            return new SelectableEntity[size];
        }
    };
}
```

for this, to work, your SelectableEntity class also must implement Parcelable.

Comment: i got this error:  ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4942): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel: unable to marshal value com.---.---.entity.SelectableEntity@a6785408

Comment: i also implement Parcelable to my SelectableEntity but when i run i got this error:  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
        java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.--.--.MyService@a671c188 with Intent { cmp=com.--.--/.MyService (has extras) }: android.os.BadParcelableException: Parcelable protocol requires a Parcelable.Creator object called  CREATOR on class com.--.--.entity.SelectableEntity

Comment: @ElhamGdz your SelectableEntity class also should contain CREATOR field as ParentActivityData contains. and if possible, post your SelectableEntity class.

Comment: also do you know about ProgressDialog ?

Comment: yeah... I can help upto I can

Comment: i have this method " final ProgressDialog progDailog = ProgressDialog.show (this, "Loading ...", true);

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
         
            public void run() {
               progDailog.dismiss();
          }
        }, 10000); " but when i run i have error.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43308/discussion-between-gopal-rao-and-elham-gdz)